# ValueError: x and y must have the same first dimension, but have different shapes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
import urllib.request  
from math import sqrt, fabs, exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from sklearn.linear_model import enet_path
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, roc_curve
import numpy

target_url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/undocumented/connectionist-bench/sonar/sonar.all-data'
data = urllib.request.urlopen(target_url)

xList = []
for line in data:
    #split on comma
    row = line.strip().split(",".encode(encoding='utf-8'))  
    xList.append(row)

xNum = []
labels = []

for row in xList:
    lastCol = row.pop()
    if lastCol == b'M':
        labels.append(1.0)
    else:
        labels.append(0.0)
    attrRow = [float(elt) for elt in row]
    xNum.append(attrRow)

nrow = len(xNum)
ncol = len(xNum[1])

alpha = 1.0

xMeans = []
xSD = []
for i in range(ncol):
    col = [xNum[j][i] for j in range(nrow)]
    mean = sum(col)/nrow
    xMeans.append(mean)
    colDiff = [(xNum[j][i] - mean) for j in range(nrow)]
    sumSq = sum([colDiff[i] * colDiff[i] for i in range(nrow)])
    stdDev = sqrt(sumSq/nrow)
    xSD.append(stdDev)

xNormalized = []
for i in range(nrow):
    rowNormalized = [(xNum[i][j] - xMeans[j])/xSD[j] for j in range(ncol)]
    xNormalized.append(rowNormalized)

meanLabel = sum(labels)/nrow
sdLabel = sqrt(sum([(labels[i] - meanLabel) * (labels[i] - meanLabel) for i in range (nrow)])/nrow)



labelNormalized = [(labels[i] - meanLabel)/sdLabel for i in range(nrow)]

nxval = 10
for ixval in range(nxval):
    idxTest = [a for a in range (nrow) if a%nxval == ixval]
    idxTrain = [a for a in range(nrow) if a%nxval != ixval]

    xTrain = numpy.array([xNormalized[r] for r in idxTrain])
    xTest = numpy.array([xNormalized[r] for r in idxTest])
    labelTrain = numpy.array([labelNormalized[r] for r in idxTrain])
    labelTest = numpy.array([labelNormalized[r] for r in idxTest])
    alphas, coefs, _ = enet_path(xTrain, labelTrain, l1_ratio = 0.8, fit_intercept=False, return_models=False)


    if ixval == 0:
        pred = numpy.dot(xTest, coefs)
        yOut = labelTest

    else:
        yTemp = numpy.array(yOut)
        yOut = numpy.concatenate((yTemp, labelTest), axis = 0)


    predTemp = numpy.array(pred)
    pred = numpy.concatenate((predTemp, numpy.dot(xTest, coefs)), axis = 0)


misClassRate = []
_,nPred = pred.shape
for iPred in range(1, nPred):
    predList = list(pred[:, iPred])
    errCnt = 0.0
    for irow in range(nrow):
        if (predList[irow] < 0.0) and (yOut[irow] >= 0.0):
            errCnt += 1.0
        elif (predList[irow] >= 0.0) and (yOut[irow] < 0.0):
            errCnt += 1.0

    misClassRate.append(errCnt/nrow)

    minError = min(misClassRate)
    idxMin = misClassRate.index(minError)
    plotAlphas = numpy.array(alphas[1:len(alphas)])
    misClassRate_np = numpy.array(misClassRate)

    plot.figure()
    plot.plot(plotAlphas, misClassRate_np, label='Misclassification Error Across Folds', linewidth=2)
    plot.axvline(plotAlphas[idxMin], linestyle='--', label='CV Estimate of Best alpha')
    plot.legend()
    plot.semilogx()
    ax = plot.gca()
    ax.invert_xaxis()
    plot.xlabel('alpha')
    plot.ylabel('Misclassification Error')
    plot.axis('tight')
    plot.show()
```

When I executed the code above, it returns: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (99,) and (1,).

It seems the problem is due to unequal length in x and y.

Then I checked both `plotAlphas` and `misClassRate_np`, they show the same length. Also, both of them has been changed to array but still fail to fix the problem. Can't figure out what's happening.

Comment: Just venturing a guess, because I won't spend time understanding the logic of code. I believe in the final loop `for iPred in range(1, nPred)`, you want up to the line `misClassRate.append(errCnt/nrow)` to be in the loop block. Intend out the rest of the code and it seems to work. This seems to line up with your intention of that accidentally intended block at the end, which is supposed to be executed at the very end, after all the looping is finished.